# ASP.NET (GridView): GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text returns the original value not the value that I just entered

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

Editing Method:

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        }
```

Updating Method:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        int _selectedRowIndex = e.RowIndex;
        int _ameintyId = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[_selectedRowIndex].Value;
        string updatedAmenity = GridView1.Rows[_selectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Text;
    }
```

*N.B: and a strange thing that I noticed, when I click edit it reloads the page but won't edit the row, so I click it again and it works .. and this happen everytime, it's not an exception or something!*

**Edit**

First of all I'm using a BoundField .. I figured out that when I add a DataKey it created a new field for it which is the ID and that what caused the problem! so I just changed the 0 to 1 .. but now I'm facing a problem that the cell Text property returns the original value not the new value!

Comment: How you are getting user input, i guess through `TextBox` inside cell 0?

Comment: Actually I use a BoundField .. could you check my edit please =) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Issue:** *To get the value I just entered instead of the original value*

Updating Method: Used e.NewValues property

```
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        int _selectedRowIndex = e.RowIndex;
        int _ameintyId = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[_selectedRowIndex].Value;
        string updatedAmenity = e.NewValues[0].ToString();
    }
```

**Second Issue:** *Clicking twice to get the edit button to work*

Editing Method: I just called my method that binds my grid

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        AmenitiesGridDataBind();
    }
```

Thanks for offering your help =)

Answer (score 0):

```
string updatedAmenity = e.NewValues[0].ToString();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43486836/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.